# How to display sql statements of existing table like the one seen in SQL Pane

Tags: postgresql

is there any easier way about SQL statements that shows the query seen in SQL pane of a certain table?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can dump the schema of a database with `pg_dump --schema-only`.

There's no direct way to get the "CREATE TABLE" statement from a query.

If you start psql with `psql -E ...` then you can see how the various backslash commands (`\dt` etc) work.